# I need to attach .mdb database to C# desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, jit

**I included the database to the project files and build the solution, when I run the application in another machine I get that error**

************** Exception Text **************

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration
>   system failed to initialize --->
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
>   configuration section configuration. (C:\Documents and
>   Settings\windows\Desktop\IstanbulFood\POSApp\IstanbulFoodPOS\bin\Debug\IstanbulFoodPOS.exe.Config
>   line 8) at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
>   ignoreLocal) at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
>   schemaErrors) at
>   System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors() at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String
>   configKey) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String
>   configKey) at
>   System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection(String
>   sectionName) at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String
>   sectionName) at
>   System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_ConnectionStrings() at
>   IstanbulFoodPOS.dataAccess..ctor() in
>   D:\IstanbulFood\POSApp\IstanbulFoodPOS\dataAccess.cs:line 17 at
>   IstanbulFoodPOS.Login.EnterButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\IstanbulFood\POSApp\IstanbulFoodPOS\Login.cs:line 37 at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
>   button, Int32 clicks) at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m) at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m) at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

************** Loaded Assemblies **************

```
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
IstanbulFoodPOS
    Assembly Version: 1.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/windows/Desktop/IstanbulFood/POSApp/IstanbulFoodPOS/bin/Debug/IstanbulFoodPOS.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.42 (RTM.050727-4200)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections> </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="IstanbulFoodDBConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\IstanbulFood\POSApp\IstanbulFoodPOS\IstanbulFoodDB‌​.mdbb;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <configuration>
        <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"/>
    </configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Maybe the other machine has a different (i.e.  newer) MS Access Runtime installed. Try `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or install Access Runtime 2007 which should work with old provider.

Comment: Thanks, your advice should be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are having trouble with connection string. You can find examples in [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/).

Example connection string should be;

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccessFile.accdb; Persist Security Info=False;
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure in another machine the file path "D:\IstanbulFood\POSApp\IstanbulFoodPOS\IstanbulFoodDB‌​.mdbb" is same?

Comment: Not sure, This path is in my own machine where I am developing the application!!!  Currently I chaged it to : |DataDirectory|\IstanbulFoodDB.mdb

Answer (score 0):

The exception is due to an additional configuration element in your app.config file. Try moving the `<system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"/>` element up one level of nesting, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections> </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="IstanbulFoodDBConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\IstanbulFood\POSApp\IstanbulFoodPOS\IstanbulFoodDB‌​.mdbb;Persist Security Info=True" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"/>

    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the Data source to :

```
Data Source =|DataDirectory|\IstanbulFoodDB.mdb;
```

And it's working when I run the application in another machine;
Here's also the `Config` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections> </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="IstanbulFoodDBConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\IstanbulFoodDB.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;" providerName="System.Data.OleDb"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true"/>

  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```